# Freefair in a multimodule Kotlin project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, aspectj, freefair-aspectj

I'm using the `io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving` plugin in my Kotlin-Gradle multi-module project to enable aspects in my springboot application.

When I tried using the plugin in a simple project it worked perfectly fine, when I then split the project into a multi-module one, it started simply not recognizing the aspects anymore

Here is a [MCVE](https://github.com/void-developer/aspect-demo-kotlin) I created on github.

So I basically setup the root project gradle file:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.3"
    id("io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving") version "6.6.3"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
}

group = "com.voiddev"

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin-spring")
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
    apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
    apply(plugin = "io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving")

    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

        implementation("org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.19")
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
            jvmTarget = "17"
        }
    }

    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

Then all I do is try to use the aspects defined in the 'common' module, within the 'server' module.
I did import correclty the common module within the server module, since I'm able to access the classes defined in the `common` module.
This is my server gradle file:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.3"
    id("io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving") version "6.6.3"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
}

group = "com.voiddev"

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":common"))
}

tasks {
    bootJar {
        archiveBaseName.set(rootProject.name)
    }
}
```

However the aspects are simply ignored

Comment: Thanks for the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For someone who normally only uses Java, Groovy and Maven, but never Gradle and Kotlin, a reproducer was the easiest way to get to the bottom of this. Please keep up the good practice to always create an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I am wondering why you use native AspectJ at all, because you apply the aspect to a Spring service. I.e., the regular "AOP lite" called Spring AOP, which comes with Spring, would suffice. For that, you do not need any extra build plugins.

Anyway, to answer your question: Your module `common` is an aspect library. To make the AspectJ compiler recognise it as such, you ought to put it on the **aspectpath**, not on the regular classpath. In Freefair, as [documented here](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/8.4/reference/#_aspectpath), this is done like this:

```kotlin
dependencies {
  aspect(project(":common"))
}
```

Then, it works. Given this server application, ...

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class ServerApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  runApplication<ServerApplication>(*args).use {
    println(it.getBean(AspectService::class.java).randomFunction())
  }
}
```

... the console log will be:

```
MetricAspect: $Proxy57
MetricAspect: $Proxy57
Hello Aspect
```

But of course, your pointcut is too generic when using native AspectJ. It will match twice, once for `call` and once for `execution` joinpoints. That would not happen in Spring AOP, because the latter only knows `execution`. You can fix it like this:

```kotlin
@After("@annotation(metricAnnotation) && execution(* *(..))")
```

The console log changes to:

```
MetricAspect: $Proxy57
Hello Aspect
```

You might also want to optionally consider upgrading the Freefair plugin from 6.6.3 to 8.4 in both modules:

```kotlin
id("io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving") version "8.4"
```

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm! As an MCVE I did a simple aspect, but in my original project I have internal methods that are called and need to be weaved with aspects